# Wiederholung des bestimmten Artikels nach "und"

Tags: article

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen

> Die Position und **die** Orientierung der Kamera werden mit dieser Gleichung beschrieben.

und

> Die Position und Orientierung der Kamera werden mit dieser Gleichung beschrieben.

Wenn es kaum einen Unterschied gibt, was macht man, wenn z.B. ein Artikel (m) und der andere (f) ist, oder ein Wort singulär und das andere Plural?

Answer (score 3):

In Deinem Beispiel gibt es keinen Unterschied in der Bedeutung, und es ist üblich den bestimmten Artikel lediglich einmalig zu nennen.

> Wenn es kaum einen Unterschied gibt, was macht man, wenn z.B. ein Artikel (m) und der andere (f) ist, oder ein Wort singulär und das andere Plural?

Sobald sich die Artikel unterscheiden, ist es in jedem Fall (stilistisch) besser die entsprechenden Artikel zu nennen.

Hier ein Beispielsatz ([Quelle](https://forum.wordreference.com/goto/post?id=1450636)):

> > Da die Fahrradwege zur Zeit von Wildwuchs überwuchert sind, raten wir Ihnen zur Nutzung der drei anderen Transportmittel: das Auto, Strassenbahn, und Bus.

Besser wäre demnach:

> > Da die Fahrradwege zur Zeit von Wildwuchs überwuchert sind, raten wir Ihnen zur Nutzung der drei anderen Transportmittel: das Auto, **die** Strassenbahn, oder **den** Bus.

Oder alle Artikel wegzulassen:

> > Da die Fahrradwege zur Zeit von Wildwuchs überwuchert sind, raten wir Ihnen zur Nutzung der drei anderen Transportmittel: Auto, Strassenbahn, oder Bus.

Comment: Irgendwie ist der 2. Teilsatz verkehrt/seltsam, oder? Zunächst einmal das Oxford Komma. Dann müsste es nicht "oder den Bus" statt "und den Bus" heißen? Stilistisch würde ich zwar die Artikel komplett weglassen, aber wenn man sie nutzt wäre das dann nicht bezugnehmend auf den Teil davor "des Autos, der Straßenbahn oder des Busses"?

Comment: @mtwde Ich denke auch, dass _oder_ besser wäre. Aber besser gar keine Artikel, oder bestimmte für jedes Subjekt.

Comment: @mtwde _"aber wenn man sie nutzt wäre das dann nicht bezugnehmend auf den Teil davor "des Autos, der Straßenbahn oder des Busses"?"_ Nein, das hört sich komplett falsch an.

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe da einen *geringfügigen* Unterschied, die beiden Sätze haben nicht wirklich *verschiedene Bedeutungen*, eher unterscheidet sich die Ansicht um eine *Nuance*:
Bei "Die Position und Orientierung der Kamera (...)" hat man eher den Eindruck, dass beide Dinge eng miteinander verbunden sind, während "Die Position und die Orientierung der Kamera (...)" eher größere Unabhängigkeit der beiden Größem voneinander suggeriert.
Der Unterschied ist jedoch minimal und fällt in den Bereich "Hohe Schule der Formulierungen". Im gewöhnlichen Umgangston ist er eher vernachlässigbar.